# How to mute Ubuntu boot up sound

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I'm a new user of Ubuntu and I keep seeing people saying to go to Preferences -> Sound and then the Sounds tab.  I don't have a sounds Tab.  I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu.

I have: Sound Effects, Hardware, Input, Output, Applications

How can I disable the boot up sound?

Comment: Sounds like you are using Karmic 9.10 - at least I'm using it and have the same problem with the suggested solutions. For older versions of Ubuntu, the solution would be to explicitly choose no sound for the boot up sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubunto 9.10 / karmic, the startup sound is handled by a startup application. You can disable (or change) the startup sound as described on http://titotheman.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/changing-startup-sound-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic/

If you just want to disable, the important bit is:

> Go to System -> Preferences -> Starup
>   Applications Look for “GNOME Login
>   Sound” in the list. If you don’t want
>   to hear anything at startup, uncheck
>   this box.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing `Sound theme` to `No Sounds` and uncheck `Enable Window and button sound checkbox`?

Comment: Same problem here. Tried what you suggested, but it just muted everything when I'm logged in, but still makes a sound on booting up.